# ng-multiselect implement syles on all items on condition

Tags: angular, typescript, multi-select, ng-options, ng-template

i want to implement dynamic styling on just one item using ids and on item2 not item1.

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown  
                    id="two"
                    name="city"
                    [settings]="dropdownSettings"
                    [data]="cities"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedItem"
                    (onSelect)="selectedItemslist(selectedItem)"
                    [ngClass]="condition1bool ? 'multicustom' : ''|| condition2bool ? 'multicustomdenter' : ''||condition3bool ? 'defaultcustom' : ''"
                    >
                  </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { EmployeeModel } from 'src/app/Models/EmployeeModel';
import { HttpService } from 'src/app/Services/http.service';
import { SharedServiceService } from 'src/app/Services/shared-service.service';

interface ICountry {
  item_id: number;
  item_text: string;
  status:number;
  color:string;
}

interface CountryDictionary {
  [key: number]: ICountry;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit{
  cities: Array<ICountry> = [];
  selectedItem: Array<ICountry> = [];
  dropdownSettings: any = {};
  condition1bool: boolean=false;
  condition2bool: boolean=false;
  condition3bool: boolean=false;
  denterbool: boolean=false;
  data: ICountry;
  arraylength:  number;
  arraylength2:  number;
  filterarraydata: Array<ICountry> = []
  
  constructor()
  {
   
  
  }
  
  ngOnInit(){

      this.cities = [
        {
          item_id: 1,
          item_text: 'Lahore',
          status:1,
          color:'red'
         
        },
        {
          item_id: 2,
          item_text: 'Islamabad',
          status:2,
          color:'yellow'
        },
        {
          item_id: 3,
          item_text: 'Karachi',
          status:3,
          color:'orange'
        },
        {
          item_id: 4,
          item_text: 'Multan',
          status:4,
          color:'brown'
        }
      ];
      this.dropdownSettings = {
        singleSelection: false,
        idField: 'item_id',
        toggleSelectAll: false,
        enableCheckAll:false,
        allowRemoteDataSearch: false,
        textField: 'item_text',
        itemsShowLimit: 2,
        
      };
    

  }
  
  getItemColors( arraydata: Array<ICountry> = []) {

    for (let user of this.cities) {
        
      if(user.item_id==1)
      {
       
        if(this.condition1bool==false)
        {
          this.condition1bool=true;
          this.condition2bool=false;
          this.condition3bool=false;
          break;
        }
        
      }
      else if(user.item_id==2)
      {
        if(this.condition2bool==false)
        {
          this.condition1bool=false;
          this.condition2bool=true;
          this.condition3bool=false;
          break;
        }
      }
      
}

  }
  selectedItemslist(arraydata: Array<ICountry> = [])
  {
    console.log('araay main length' +arraydata.length);
    if(arraydata.length==1)
    {
      this.arraylength=arraydata.length;
      this.getItemColors(this.filterarraydata);
    }
    if(arraydata.length>1)
    {
      this.filterarraydata=arraydata;
      this.filterarraydata.splice(0, arraydata.length-this.arraylength);
      this.arraylength=arraydata.length;
      console.log('araay lengtha after splice ' + this.filterarraydata);
      this.getItemColors(this.filterarraydata);
    }
  }
  
 
  
  
}
```

```
.multicustom
{
    .multiselect-item-checkbox input[type='checkbox']:checked + div {
 
        color: green !important;
        
    }
}
.multicustomdenter
{
    .multiselect-item-checkbox input[type='checkbox']:checked + div {
 
        color: yellow !important;
        
    }
   
}
.defaultcustom
{
    .multiselect-item-checkbox input[type='checkbox']:checked + div {
 
        color: orange !important;
        
    }
}
```

when i add these classes when id=1 or id=2 at first item selection it works fine but at second selection it implements styles on all previous checked items also. but i want to add dynamically styles on each item index using id as status. And ng-multiselect is not picking ng-template.